# How to use --hash-modules and --module-path options of JDK 9 jar tool?

Tags: jar, java-9, module-path

I would like to compute and record the hash of module matched by the given pattern that depend upon directly on a modular JAR file being updated. For this a use `--hash-modules` and `--module-path` options.
There are my tries:

```
jar --hash-modules com.me.util --module-path "dist\com.me.jar;dist\com.me.util.jar"  --update --file dist/com.me.jar --main-class=com.me.A --verbose --module-version 0.1 -C build/modules/com.me module-info.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/A.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/B.class

jar --hash-modules "com.me.util;com.me.util" --module-path "dist\com.me.jar;dist\com.me.util.jar"  --update --file dist/com.me.jar --main-class=com.me.A --verbose --module-version 0.1 -C build/modules/com.me module-info.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/A.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/B.class
```

When I try to do it I get the warning message: "no module is recorded in hash in com.me".

These commands will create the *.jar files (modules) without any errors, but they won't add any hash information. I would like to see this information and take advantage of this functionality (`--hash-modules` and `--module-path` options). Please, tell me how to do it!

---

The complete structure of the project folders can be found [here](https://github.com/java1cprog/Java9-jar/tree/master/NetbeansProjects/my_ch1_9).

My experiments and working examples of using the jar tool's options are [here](https://github.com/java1cprog/Java9-jar).

The following operations described in [Java Platform, Standard Edition Tools Reference (jar)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867__GUID-44BCC07B-1A03-4FEE-884B-EF057B22299F).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Uddhav Gautam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7232295/uddhav-gautam), thank you for the [link](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) to additional documentation.

After reading carefully the documentation ([Packaging: Modular JAR files (JEP 261: Module System)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Packaging:-Modular-JAR-files) and [`--hash-modules=PATTERN` (Java Platform, Standard Edition Tools Reference)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867__GUID-44BCC07B-1A03-4FEE-884B-EF057B22299F)), I realized what parameters should be given to solve this task.

Here's a working example:

```
#Working command:
#Create module:
jar --hash-modules "com.me" --module-path "dist/com.me.jar" --verbose --create --file dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class  build/modules/com.me.util/com/me/util/Util.class
jar --hash-modules "com.me" --module-path "dist/com.me.jar" -v -c -f dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class  build/modules/com.me.util/com/me/util/Util.class

#Update module:
jar --hash-modules "com.me" --module-path "dist/com.me.jar" --verbose --update --file dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class
jar --hash-modules "com.me" --module-path "dist/com.me.jar" -v -u -f dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class
```

To see the result of the options, use the following command:

```
#Describe module:
jar --file dist/com.me.util.jar --describe-module
```

The result should be like this:

```
com.me.util jar:file:///C:/my_ch1_9/dist/com.me.util.jar/!module-info.class
exports com.me.util
requires java.base mandated
hashes com.me SHA-256 85c0539e4ca9a01b00f4c29a1a8b01cd452d1d97f437166b8bb415046dac65cb
```

Comment: What happens if you do                                `jar --hash-modules "com.me.jar" --module-path "dist" --verbose --create --file dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class  build/modules/com.me.util/com/me/util/Util.class` AND
`jar --hash-modules "com.me.jar" --module-path "dist" -v -c -f dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class  build/modules/com.me.util/com/me/util/Util.class`

Comment: The first command will recreate the jar file, but the hash information will not be added. The warning information will be printed: 

warning: no module is recorded in hash in com.me.util
added manifest
added module-info: module-info.class
adding: com/me/util/Util.class(in = 411) (out= 268)(deflated 34%)

Comment: The second command will do the same:
warning: no module is recorded in hash in com.me.util
added manifest
added module-info: module-info.class
adding: com/me/util/Util.class(in = 411) (out= 268)(deflated 34%)

Answer (score 2):

`--hash-modules <ProvidePatternHere>` /* you are missing pattern */

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261

Hashes are only recorded for modules whose names match the regular expression

```
--module-path <LinkToModule>
```

So, a complete example would be something like below:

```
jar --hash-modules "*.jar" --module-path "dist" ... and your other stuffs here.
```

Comment: This example will not be valid: an error will be (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Error in message file at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.getMsg(Main.java:194) ...)) jar --hash-modules "*.jar" --module-path "dist" --update --file dist/com.me.jar --main-class=com.me.A --verbose --module-version 0.1 -C build/modules/com.me module-info.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/A.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/B.class